# anjuta code-completion in Debian

Tags: linux, ide, debian, anjuta

Can you share your experience with making code-completion work in Anjuta, at least for C/C++?
It had failed to code-complete both references to inside my code and to various libraries (GLib, etc) as well.

I tried several times to make it work 'out-of-the-box' in Debian Lenny/Squeeze and failed -- no matter, which of editors I was using -- Scintilla-based or the other one :)

I was under impression that making this part of Anjuta work would allow me to use 'native gnome' IDE for development, so I would be glad if you know solution.